# Installation of Xdebug in wamp(2.0)

Tags: php, installation, wamp, xdebug

In php.ini file

```
;xdebug Configuration

zend_extension="C:/TenthPlanet/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc6.dll" 
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=localhost
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always 
xdebug.remote_port=9000 
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
xdebug.profiler_enable=1 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:/TenthPlanet/wamp/tmp/xdebug" 
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=On 
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_mode=req 
xdebug.remote_log="C:/TenthPlanet/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
```

But its not installing. When i copied my phpinfo source in xdebug.org/wizrad.php its saying my compiler MSVC6  needs to be upgrade MSVC9 (microsoft visual studio C++). Then I installed the latest one but its not working.

Its not installing properly guys. So whats is the problem ?

My configuration is

PHP - 5.3.0
Apache - 2.2.11

Comment: use phpinfo() to get all configuration info then check if xdebug present there??

Comment: I already installed its coming as enabled but its not working in eclipse.

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug Have you gone through this?

Comment: I go the solution by correcting the PHP.ini file. Actually i am loading it as PHP extension. It should load it as zend extension. Thanks

Comment: And how did you do that? I though typing zend_extension="...." in the php.ini file would be enough to load it as a zend extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9.dll` instead or the `php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc6.dll`

Alternatively run [this wizard](http://www.xdebug.org/wizard.php) on the XDEBUG site, do as it says and copy and paste the output from your phpinfo into it and it will tell you which version you need automatically.

Comment: No i got the solution actually i am loading it as `php extension` but it should loaded as zend extension. In PHP.ini i corrected & its working fine. Thanks